# dxl findPlainText check does not match string

Tags: ibm-doors

I have a subroutine that I pass a string value from a skip list. That value is compared to objects in a Doors File. But the comparison does not work.

```
Skip split (string s, string delim)
{
   Skip skp = create
   int i = 0
   Regexp split = regexp "^(.*?)" delim "(.*)$"
   while (split s)
   { 
      string temp_s = s[match 2]
      put(skp, i++, s[match 1] "")
      s = temp_s
   }
   put(skp, i++, s "")
   return skp
}

string getInfo( string inStr)
{
   for currObj in currMod do
   {
      if ( findPlainText( ( currOBJ.SW_VRC ""), inStr, offsetFromFind, lengthFromFind, false ) )
      {
         print currOBJ.SW_VRC " matches " inStr "\n";
      }
    }
}

Skip newLst = split(modname, ",")  // this just splits a string input into parameters separated by commas

string inputInfo;

find(newLst, 0, inputInfo)

getInfo(inputInfo)
```

Now this is a simplified version of what I am doing. But the findPlainText does not match anything. inputInfo is getting the correct string, I checked.
The part that really kills me is if I hardcode in the parameter

i.e. inStr = "21";

It works like it's supposed to.
Now I was assuming a string is a string. Is there a difference between a string from a skip list and a  string that's quoted? Is there a hidden character?
What am I missing? Any insight you could provide would be welcome.

Thanks,
DevM

Answer (score 0):

your snippet works, but I had to add some variables to make it work, and I don't have a split function at hand:

```
Skip split (string s, string delim)
{
   Skip skp = create
   int i = 0
   Regexp split = regexp "^(.*?)" delim "(.*)$"
   while (split s)
   { 
      string temp_s = s[match 2]
      put(skp, i++, s[match 1] "")
      s = temp_s
   }
   put(skp, i++, s "")
   return skp
}
string SW_VRC="Object Text"
Module currMod = current Module
string getInfo( string inStr)
{
   int offsetFromFind, lengthFromFind
   string resultString = "" 
   Object currObj
   for currObj in currMod do
   {
      if ( findPlainText( ( currObj.SW_VRC ""), inStr, offsetFromFind, lengthFromFind, false ) )
      {
         print currObj.SW_VRC " matches " inStr "\n";
         resultString = resultString "\n" currObj.SW_VRC ""
      }
    }
    return resultString
}
string modname = "a,b,cc,ccc,d,e,f"
Skip newLst = split (modname,",")

string inputInfo= "";

find(newLst, 0, inputInfo)

getInfo(inputInfo)
```

Perhaps you removed too much information when preparing this post?
Or you don't have an entry with the key "0" in newLst? What happens if you start your function with

```
string inputInfo
inputInfo = "21"
getInfo (inputInfo)
```

?

Comment: Mike. I added the split subroutine I am using to the original post. It had never occurred to me that the string in the skip list might be the culprit. Also, I do start at 0. But the zero entry is a directory path and is not used by the getInfo subroutine. Anything from 1 on I feed to this routine.

Comment: Paul, I added your split function to my code, for me, it still works. Have you by chance added autodeclare somewhere? This would prevent you from seeing problems in the code by using undeclared variables. 
You say that you feed anything from 1 to the routine, but in your code you only add  the zero entry to the routine.
Please compare your code snippet with mine, try if mine works for you  as well . The output of the above snippet with one of my modules is:

IEC 61508 V6.7 Deutsch_SW_DD_Life_Design_General_520, matches a
IEC 61508 V6.7 Deutsch_SW_DD_Life_Design_General_521, matches a...